# Get Mouse Wheel movement data

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have wrote a window hook to retrieve the mouse events

```
_handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,
                    (HOOKPROC)KeyEvent,
                    nullptr,
                    GetCurrentThreadId());

static LRESULT WINAPI KeyEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(nCode >= 0)
    {
         MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* mStruct = ( MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
         MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* mWheelDStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

         CMouseHookCom::_this->ReportEventW(mStruct->hwnd, wParam, mWheelDStruct);
    }

    return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        OutputDebugString(L"CMouseHookCom-WM_MOUSEWHEEL");
        strm = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)extraData;
        zDelta = (short)(HIWORD(((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)extraData)->mouseData));
        _stprintf(buffer, L"CMouseHookCom - WM_MOUSEWHEEL delta %d %i", zDelta, short((strm->mouseData >> 16) & 0xffff));
        OutputDebugString(buffer);
        if (zDelta > 0)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"CMouseHookCom-WM_MOUSEWHEEL UP");
            Invoke_onScrollOut(componentId);
        }
        else
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"CMouseHookCom-WM_MOUSEWHEEL DOWN");
            Invoke_onScrollIn(componentId);
        }
        break;
    default:
        _stprintf(buffer, L"CMouseHookCom - UnHandleled event %d", event);
        OutputDebugString(buffer);
        break;
    }
```

no matter how I try I always get positive results of the wheel. Also I always get different value. What is the correct way to retrieve the data?

Comment: You cannot use MSLLHOOKSTRUCT in a WH_MOUSE callback.  Wheel messages are special, they are sent instead of posted.  You must use a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook to see them.

Comment: `WH_MOUSE` uses `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`.  `WH_MOUSE_LL` uses `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`. Hense the struct names.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead of a mouse hook.  That is less overhead on the OS to monitor the mouse, and it gives you information that a hook would not.